# Error:(104, 39) error: cannot pass object of non-trivial type 'cv::Mat' through variadic method; call will abort at runtime [-Wnon-pod-varargs]

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am using jni develop opencv 
and i try transfer the Mat passed to the java in c ++
but i get this error,

here is my C++ code

```
void ocrPricetagNeedCallJavaMethodToApi(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, Mat image) {
    jclass class1 = env->FindClass("mvp/module/cashback/fragment/RecetptDiscernFragment");
    jmethodID method = env->GetMethodID(class1, "nativeProcessFramePriceTagResult", "(Lorg/opencv/core/Mat;)V");
    env->CallVoidMethod(thiz, method, image);
}
```

here is my java code

```
public void nativeProcessFramePriceTagResult(Mat image) {
    if (null != image) {

    } else{

    }
}
```

anyone can help me ?

Comment: Well, you obviously cannot pass an instance of the C++ `Mat` class as a Java `Mat` instance. If you want to get a `Mat` to Java from C++ you have a few different options, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28600003/return-array-of-mat-from-jni-to-java

Comment: i have try it ,but is not work .

Comment: That doesn't really tell us anything unless you show in your question exactly what you've tried, and the exact error(s) you're getting.

Comment: int sizes = image.total() * image.elemSize();
    byte * bytes = new byte[sizes];  
    std::memcpy(bytes,image.data,sizes * sizeof(byte));     i try do this .but something error .  this 'image' is my mat

Comment: What is that code supposed to achieve? You just allocate some new memory and copy some data to it.

Comment: thanks a lot , i have solve it !